# Fetched Data to State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

**UserAPI.js** This is what i export to the **Admin.js**

```
     export const getAllEmailsFromConfirmedUsers = () => { Axios.get('http://localhost:8080/users/confirmedusers')
     .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

**Admin.js** -
How i import the API call.

```
import {getAllEmailsFromConfirmedUsers} from '../../shared/api/UserAPI'
```

**Admin.js** - I then use the function inside `useEffect()`

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getAllEmailsFromConfirmedUsers();
  });
```

This is my state inside my **Admin.js** file.

```
  const [myState, setMyState] = useState([]);
```

---

This works fine, and i get a array of values back from the fetched API call, but to 
**my question:** How can i set the retrieved array into my state(*setMyState*) when importing the Axios function from an external file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your UserAPI do this:

```
export const getAllEmailsFromConfirmedUsers = () => { 
 return Axios.get('http://localhost:8080/users/confirmedusers')
  }
```

Then in your Admin:

```
useEffect(() => {
 getAllEmailsFromConfirmedUsers().then({
//Do Your update here

 }).catch(error=>{
  })
```

});

Answer (score 1):

You can give a callback to your api call function

```
export const getAllEmailsFromConfirmedUsers = (saveData) => { 
 Axios.get('http://localhost:8080/users/confirmedusers')
     .then(function (response) {
      if(response){
        saveData(response)
      }
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

and in your component:

```
useEffect(() => {
  getAllEmailsFromConfirmedUsers(setMyState);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting your data but not returning your data anywhere. Get rid of the console logs and add `return response` in your API calls.

```
   export const getAllEmailsFromConfirmedUsers = () => { Axios.get('http://localhost:8080/users/confirmedusers')
     .then(response => response)
     .catch(err => err);
  }
```

Next you will be making an async call inside useEffect so you can structure your functions this way. This will store your response in a variable and you will be able to set your state

```
const [myState, setMyState] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchMyData() {
        return await getAllEmailsFromConfirmedUsers();
    }

    let myEmails = fetchMyData()
    setMyState(myEmails)
}, [])
```

Comment: Gives me this when i `console.log(myEmails)` 
https://i.gyazo.com/b792c7b11f2dbcf016708f398b5402bc.png

Comment: yes, thats ok, use another .then to resolve that promise. do state update n second then block

Comment: In first then block you got a promise when you returned response. then you can use another then block right after it to resolve that response, this time youb will have data not promise.